# Aurelia upgrade from core skeleton causes validation issue

Tags: aurelia

I have recently upgraded an Aurelia typescript/ASPNETCORE/Webpack project. I don't recall exactly, but I think I used a template similar to this:

https://github.com/vuorinem/aspnet-aurelia-webpack-skeleton

Worked great. However, upon upgrade, the ONLY plugin that fails is aurelia-validation. This is the boot.ts file:

boot.ts

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap';

declare const IS_DEV_BUILD: boolean; // The value is supplied by Webpack during the build

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-validation'))
        .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-cookie'))
        .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-dialog'))
        .feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('app/components/common/index'));

    if (IS_DEV_BUILD) {
        aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
    }

    new HttpClient().configure(config => {
        const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
        config.withBaseUrl(baseUrl);
    });

    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app/components/app/app')));
}
```

The other two plugins behave... but when 'aurelia-validation' attempts to load, it fails thus:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid resource path [function ValidateBindingBehavior() {
    return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
}]. Resources must be specified as relative module IDs.
at FrameworkConfiguration.globalResources (aurelia-framework.js:330)
at Object.configure (aurelia-validation.js:1782)
at aurelia-framework.js:186
```

When I set a breakpoint in aurelia-framwork.js, the resource loading up is not a string. All other sources load up with that string. Could this be some sort of typings issue?

```
for (var i = 0, ii = toAdd.length; i < ii; ++i) {
  resource = toAdd[i];
  if (typeof resource !== 'string') {
    ====> throw new Error('Invalid resource path [' + resource + ']. Resources must be specified as relative module IDs.');
  }
```

When it throws, resource is evaluating as:
[Function - not a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHim2.png)

Comment: Can you delete your package lock, node_modules folder and reinstall everything? I think you got some old version packages in there